# UI Navigation Controller Showing Null for switching to detail view

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a tab based application. On the first tab I have several views one of which is a navigation controller.  My goal is to load this list view(working) then goto a detailview on the cell click(not working).

On the cell click I am logging

> NSLog(@"%@",self.navigationController);

which is returning a null. I can only assume that I have not done something right with setting up the navigation controller but I do not know what.

on button click the table view is called:

```
#import "Reviews.h"
#import "XMLParser.h"
#import "Detailed_Review.h"

@implementation Reviews

@synthesize reviewsTableView;

XMLParser *xmlParser;
CGRect dateFrame;
UILabel *dateLabel;
CGRect contentFrame;
UILabel *contentLabel;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return [[xmlParser reviews] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
Review_Object *currentReview = [[xmlParser reviews] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        CGRect contentFrame = CGRectMake(10, 2, 265, 30);
        UILabel *contentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentFrame];
        contentLabel.tag = 0011;
        contentLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
        contentLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:contentLabel];

        CGRect reviewFrame = CGRectMake(10, 40, 265, 10);
        UILabel *reviewLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:reviewFrame];
        reviewLabel.tag = 0012;
        reviewLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:reviewLabel];
    }

UILabel *contentLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:0011];
    contentLabel.text = [currentReview rating];

UILabel *dateLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:0012];
    dateLabel.text = [currentReview review];

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 55;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
     Detailed_Review *dvController = [[Detailed_Review alloc] initWithNibName:@"Detailed_Review" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.navigationController);
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc] loadXMLByURL:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/api/reviews/xml.php?page=1"];

    self.title = @"Reviews";
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setReviewsTableView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

xib photos:

[image: first tab.xim]

[image: devtailview.xib]

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "XMLParser.h"
#import "Review_Object.h"

@interface Reviews : UIViewController

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *reviewsTableView;

@end
```

Comment: You omitted the part where the navigationController is allocated and initialized. Can you add that, including the relevant part from the .h file too?

Comment: Well I added the the .h file. As far as allocating and initializing goes I think thats what I am missing. How does does one do such a thing. Is it the same as an IBAction or IBOutlet?

Comment: Either create it with IB or programatically, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerPGforiOSLegacy/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011381-CH103-SW27

Comment: OK read the docs with no luck.  Any one have an example not on the main xib and not declaring it in the app delegate. So a tab based app that has a button on the first tab that loads a list that loads a detail view?    I follow the doc and just get a sig everytime I connect the myNavController to the NavController in the connection inspector.  When the button calls the list.

Comment: ok got it  [self presentViewController:myNav animated:YES completion:nil]; I was trying to load the viewcontroller and not the navController   duh

Comment: @0tt Can you put your answer in an answer so I can accept it please?

Comment: I don't know which answer you mean, I added both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You omitted the part where the navigationController is allocated and initialized. Can you add that, including the relevant part from the .h file too?

Either create it with IB or programatically, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerPGforiOSLegacy/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011381-CH103-SW27